# compile error: expected expression before ‘{’ token

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am getting the error

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
```

when trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    int Seat[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int x = rand()%5;
    int y = rand()%10;

    int i, j;
    do {
        printf("What class would you like to sit in, first (1) or economy (2)?");
        scanf("%d", &j);
        if(j == 1){
            Seat[x] = 1;
            printf("your seat number is %d and it is type %d\n", x, j);
        }
        else{
            Seat[y] = 1;
            printf("your seat number is %d and is is type %d\n", y, j);
        }
    }while(Seat[10] != {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1});
}
```

Background: The program is designed to be an airline seat reservation system.

Comment: This reads like homework. Is it?

Comment: it is part of a weekly lab, i just couldn't be boathered describing the question ahaha

Comment: I don't think it's very classy to expect others to do more work because you *couldn't be boathered*

Comment: The compiler usually gives you the line and at which it stopped understanding your program. You can use that information to easily find bugs. (line 22 in your case.)

Comment: i didn't say that, i said i couldn't be boathered descirbing the question, as you can see i've done the code, but i keep getting a compiling error and am not sure why i am getting it... i'm also unsure if my code is correct, so all i am asking is if someone can check my code and explain to me why i'm getting the compiling errors..

Comment: nice 5/10 chance of getting first class when picking economy, I know what I am flying. Of course that one seat is going to be pretty full.

Comment: It is spelled "bothered", the one you keep writing sounds like it has something to do with boats ;)

Comment: where is the message ”Next flight leaves in 3 hours.” in your code?

Comment: ok ok, i'm terrible with programming, unfortunately i will probably only scrape by with it, after this semester i'm done with it forever! so i really am useless with this! ahah. i'm working on it at the moment

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
 while(Seat[10] != {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1});
```

is not valid C syntax. I would add a some variable like `allOccupied` and do the following:

```
bool allOccupied = false;
do
{
   ...
   //Check if all Seats are occupied and set allOccupied to true if they are
}
while (!allOccupied);
```

Another alternative would be to add something like:

```
int Full[10] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
do
{
}
while(memcmp(Full, Seat, sizeof(Full));
```

Comment: hmm, ok, i seem to be getting a similar result to my first try, my only problem now is how do i make my code generate random seat numbers :|. when i run my code it generates the same seat number each time even though im using srand

Comment: `x` and `y` will get fixed values outside the `while` loop and will never change.

Comment: why boathering with randomness? assign the next free seat

Comment: Only way i knew aha, how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the following to check if all the array elements are 1:

```
while(Seat[10] != {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1});
```

which is incorrect. You need to run a loop and check each element or a better way is to keep a count of elements that have been changed from `0` to `1` and use that count to break the loop.